# mysql left join very slow & mysql server down

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 MySQL innoDb tables (shown as table_name:column_list):

```
meter_type: id, meter_type (primary key id)
tag_type: id, meter_type_id (primary key id, foreign key meter_type_id(meter_type table))
tag: id, tag_type_id(primary key id, foreign key tag_type_id(tag_type table))
```

i have tag: id
I would like to find meter_type that have been level 1, level 2, or level 3. 
my query is

```
SELECT m.`meter_type`
  FROM `tag` t  
          LEFT JOIN `tag_type` tt 
              ON tt.`id` = t.`tag_type_id`  
          LEFT JOIN `meter_type` m 
              ON m.`id` = tt.`meter_type_id`  
 WHERE t.`id` = '10'
```

it is too very slow taking 4-4 minutes and this query makes mysql server down.

how to solve this problem... any other way to write this query with speed

Comment: Use `explain` to analyize  your query and add proper indexes.

Comment: And if indexing doesn't help, You can fire 3 diff queries it would be completed in less than 20 seconds... :)

Answer (score 2):

I bet you have not add an index on this fields: `tag_type_id` and `meter_type_id`. Here's a **[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)** on how to properly add an index on your fields.